# Compile all SCSS files in folder

Tags: sass

I have a folder with several SCSS files and use `Visual Studio Code` with `SCSS IntelliSense` (but it's the same problem with `Sass Autocompile` or `Live Sass Compiler`)

```
config.scss
reset.scss
styles.scss
```

In my `config.scss` I have the variables like

```
$fontFamily: "Arial";
$fontSize: 16px;
$bgColor: red;
```

This is what's in my `reset.scss`

```
body {
    font-family: $fontFamily;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

To get one CSS file in the end, my `styles.scss` looks like this:

```
@import "config.scss";
@import "reset.scss";
```

The problem is, that when I change something in my `config.scss` the changes won't be applied in all other files and compiles correctly. I always had to save my `styles.scss` to make this happen.

How can I get it work that when I change something in my config-File it also compiles all files (or at least the ones variables from `config.scss` are used)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your sass is watching and compiling just the single file styles.scss

Also check those settings

```
scss.scannerDepth
Type: number
Default: 30
The maximum number of nested directories to scan.

scss.scannerExclude
Type: string[]
Default: ["**/.git", "**/node_modules", "**/bower_components"]
List of glob patterns for directories that are excluded when scanning.

scss.scanImportedFiles

Type: boolean
Default: true
Allows scan imported files.
```

[image]